# Don't know how to prevent constraints from breaking

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I am new in iOS development. i am creating a chat app with autolayouts but i am getting "breaking constraint" whenever i open collectionview in my app.
Here error which i get

```
2017-11-06 07:34:52.838630+0530 ChatHub[4083:306096] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002989c0 BubbleView.width == 205.938   (active, names: BubbleView:0x7ffde3611880 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000298600 ProfileImageView.width == 32   (active, names: ProfileImageView:0x7ffde3611a60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400028d890 H:|-(8)-[ProfileImageView](LTR)   (active, names: ProfileImageView:0x7ffde3611a60, '|':ChatHub.ChatMessageCell:0x7ffde360e670 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002988d0 H:[ProfileImageView]-(8)-[BubbleView](LTR)   (active, names: BubbleView:0x7ffde3611880, ProfileImageView:0x7ffde3611a60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000298880 BubbleView.right == ChatHub.ChatMessageCell:0x7ffde360e670.right - 8   (active, names: BubbleView:0x7ffde3611880 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000004870d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' ChatHub.ChatMessageCell:0x7ffde360e670.width == 375   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002989c0 BubbleView.width == 205.938   (active, names: BubbleView:0x7ffde3611880 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2017-11-06 07:34:53.041831+0530 ChatHub[4083:306096] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000485c30 BubbleView.width == 205.938   (active, names: BubbleView:0x7ffde345dfb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000485aa0 ProfileImageView.width == 32   (active, names: ProfileImageView:0x7ffde345e190 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000485a00 H:|-(8)-[ProfileImageView](LTR)   (active, names: ProfileImageView:0x7ffde345e190, '|':ChatHub.ChatMessageCell:0x7ffde345b380 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000485b40 BubbleView.right == ChatHub.ChatMessageCell:0x7ffde345b380.right - 8   (active, names: BubbleView:0x7ffde345dfb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000485b90 H:[ProfileImageView]-(8)-[BubbleView](LTR)   (active, names: BubbleView:0x7ffde345dfb0, ProfileImageView:0x7ffde345e190 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400029a810 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' ChatHub.ChatMessageCell:0x7ffde345b380.width == 375   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000485c30 BubbleView.width == 205.938   (active, names: BubbleView:0x7ffde345dfb0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

How can i fix this. i am stuck here from last 2 days .. please help

[image]

> i get error in above screenshot but i don't get one in below

[image]

Comment: This warning means that the constraints listed are mutually exclusive; i.e. at least one of them conflicts with one of the other ones. You will need to look at your constraints, figure out which ones conflict, and fix those.

Comment: i try to figure out but no luck! can you please be explain what going on !! output look as i want. but get this error in console.. what else i can share to get the answer.

Comment: It's hard to determine the problem without knowing your specific layout.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see your horizontal constraints for this cell look like this.

```
H:|-8-[ProfileImageView(=32)]-8-[BubbleView(=206)]-8-|
```

So pretty much your layout is fine when your view's width is equal to the sum of widths of all its subviews and spaces around them (*which is 254*). Troubles start when the cell gets wider (or narrower).

Here you can see that your configured width conflicts with the encapsulated width of your cell (*which is 375*).

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000004870d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' ChatHub.ChatMessageCell:0x7ffde360e670.width == 375   (active)>
```

If you want to keep the width of the profile image and the bubble view fixed. I recommend you to set the sign of the constraint below (`BubbleView.right`) to the greater than or equal.

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000298880 BubbleView.right == ChatHub.ChatMessageCell:0x7ffde360e670.right - 8   (active, names: BubbleView:0x7ffde3611880 )>
```

Another option is ensuring that the width of your cell is always equal to 254 which a bit harder to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error info, it seems that you create a `BubbleView` and a `ProfileImageView` side by side. The autolayout constraint is

```
(left edge)| - (8) - Profile(32) - (8) -- Bubble -- (8)| (cell right edge)
```

Notice that as long as the width of the cell is determined, that Bubble size can be automatically calculated by `cell.width - 8 - 32 - 8 - 8`. So the constraint of bubble width is redundant. Just remove it.

Comment: okay. but i don't want my bubble view to have dynamic width or automatic calculated width

Comment: Then just remove the constraint between the bubble right edge and the cell right edge.

Comment: Or the width constraint on the cell.

Comment: but constraint of bubble view is always hug to right!
i added the screenshot..!!

Comment: I notice that only the bubbles without profile images is mis-placed. You should apply different constraints for those cells.

Comment: okay.. but sometime they work perfectly and i don't even find any mistake in constraints. i can share the code if you want.